# How Can Powershell Function Be Executed Remotely Using CMD?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I want to execute the powershell function below:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe','C:\Users\<User>\Downloads\putty.exe')
```

I have used the powershell code above on the main cmd terminal at it works

But,

Using the below cmd command remotely:

```
**cmd /c
```

I have tried the code below but its not working:

```
cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe','C:\Users\<User>\Downloads\putty.exe')
```

```
cmd /c powershell.exe -c (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe','C:\Users\<User>\Downloads\putty.exe')
```

Please, I need solution. Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does this have to do with CMD.  It's all to do with Powershell and NOTHING to do with CMD.

Comment: If I am to execute this remotely how do I place it?

Comment: What happens when you doublequote the `/c` option? What happens when you doublequote the `-c`ommand? What about when you quote both appropriately? And remember that environment variables, can be useful, especially when you're trying to hide your information, `C:\Users\\ ` can often be replaced with `%UserProfile%\ `.

Comment: `wmic /node:127.0.0.1 process call Create "Notepad.exe"` is using WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) which is the Windows implementation of WBEM (Web Based Enterprise Management) and is how all languages do it. WMIC is the command line interface. Of course it would be easier to copy the file `copy c:\putty.exe \\127.0.0.1\c$\putty.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Why use cmd code from powershell? Use this:

```
$wc = New-Object System.Net.Webclient; $wc.DownloadFile('The url', 'C:\Users\Downloads\Putty.exe')
```

To invoke it remotely use this:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName TheComputerNameWhereToExecute -ScriptBlock {$wc = New-Object System.Net.Webclient; $wc.DownloadFile('The url', 'C:\Users\Downloads\Putty.exe')}
```

Comment: I need to use cmd, an example is opening notepad.exe with cmd below
cmd /c notepad.exe. But I need to use cmd to download and also execute the file via http or https. ANy solution?